# How can I use Ctrl+ScrollLock to simulate a mouse right click

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using Autohotkey 1.0.48.5 .

I can use the following code to simulate a right click by Ctrl+0 , tried an worked fine.

```
^0:: 
SendInput {Click,Right}
return
```

However, I hope I can use Ctrl+ScrollLock to do the same, but the following code does not work.

```
^ScrollLock:: 
SendInput {Click,Right}
return
```

Can someone help me out. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autohotkey forum helped me out. Using scancode(0x46) instead of 'ScrollLock' does the trick.

So I have to write:

```
^SC046:: 
SendInput {Click,Right}
return
```

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=473945

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
Ctrl & ScrollLock::
SendInput {Click,Right}
return
```

Comment: Was going to also suggest the ampersand.

Comment: Sorry, It does not work. But if I replace 'ScrollLock' with '0' , Ctrl+0 will work -- even with latest Autohotkey 1.1.03.00 .

Comment: Indeed, and it seems to work with ^CapsLock. Interesting...